# Spring Cloud Stream 1.0.0-RELEASE and Threads

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Previously when I was using RC2, I observed that each kafka consumer seemed to be executing in its own thread (in this example, **pool-6-thread-1**):

```
2016-05-13 12:13:14 pool-6-thread-1 DEBUG KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ReceivingHandler:115 - org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ReceivingHandler@2b461688 received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[400], headers={kafka_offset=17, kafka_messageKey=null, kafka_topic=redeemed, kafka_partitionId=0, kafka_nextOffset=18}] - {}
```

But after upgrading to 1.0.0RELEASE, it seems the same thread (**kafka-binder-**)is being used for all consumption, regardless of setting the `concurrency` property:

```
2016-05-17 14:14:18 kafka-binder- DEBUG KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ReceivingHandler:115 - org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ReceivingHandler@5044f552 received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[287], headers={kafka_offset=62, kafka_messageKey=null, kafka_topic=error.redeemed.poc, kafka_partitionId=0, kafka_nextOffset=63}] - {}
```

Is this the new default behavior? How do I configure my application to utilize a pool of MessageChannelBinders that each execute in their own threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pool is used but, unfortunately, the threads are all given the same name.

This is a bug - I [created an issue for it](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/543).

Comment: Fyi, the issue has now been fixed and will be available in both 1.1 and 1.0.1